# Jenkins: JAVA_HOME is not displayed in Jenkins build Environment Variables page

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, environment-variables

**Goal:** 
What I want to achieve is that for the *Jenkins job > build > Environment Variables page*, I will be able to see in the table the variable **JAVA_HOME**

**Scenario:**
I use *Jenkins>Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > JDK > JDK Installations* to define different version of java from 1.4 - 1.8. 
[image: Global JDK Installation]

I run a Jenkins job to build an ANT project using Java 1.4. The node where I run this command is in the master.

On the Jenkins job, 
[image: Choosing JDK version from job]

**Main Problem:**

Environment: In the master node, I do not have a defined **JAVA_HOME** environment variable.

Result: The build is successful. In the batch script, I echo **%JAVA_HOME%** and the selected JDK path in the job is correct which is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\j2sdk-1_4_2_19
```

However, the problem is I do not have **JAVA_HOME** displayed in
*http://JENKINS_URL/jenkins/job/MY_JOB/3/injectedEnvVars/* as normally it would have.

**Main question: How to display JAVA_HOME in the environment variables page?**

So what I tried to do, is the following:

**Secondary Problem**

Environment: In the master node, I have defined `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172` and `PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Result: The build fails because the java version is not the one that is required. In the batch script, I echo **%JAVA_HOME%** and the selected JDK path in the job is indeed incorrect which is

**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172**

In addition, JAVA_HOME variable can now be seen in that jenkins build environment variables page.

**Secondary Question:** My question in this secondary problem is that why the job specific JDK option JDK v1.4 chosen did not override or replaced the one that is configured in the master node?

Comment: Have you restarted Jenkins after setting those? Also just to confirm, Windows not Linux? Also are the env set on your user profile? Or system wide? What user is Jenkins running as?

Comment: @dann.dev, yes. I restarted Jenkins every time I  make changes in the System Environment Variables... OS is windows.